# parsing Json in .NET

Tags: .net, json

```
{ "posOrder":
{ "No": 1234,
"Operator": 18,
"ECR-Name": "Imbissbude ",
"Receipt": {
"PLUs": [
{ "Number": 31, "Name": "Pommes", "Price": 150, "Qty": 2 },
{ "Number": 112, "Name": "Coke", "Price": 200, "Qty": 1 } ]
}
}
}
```

this is my json script. i want to get each field and its value if **only**  the class name="**posOrder**". ie find filed"no" and its value, field plus and its inner fileds and values. etc.

Answer (score 1):

This library can help you with that: [Json.NET](http://json.codeplex.com/)
And then you can use LINQ to find things: [Example](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/SelectToken.html)

Answer (score 0):

Another option is Microsoft's System.Web.Extensions.dll. There is a JSON parser in the System.Web.Script.Serialization namespace.